# How to solve conflicting java methods

Tags: java, methods

Is there a way that I can not use the below method which just returns the handlerequests ? I just don't want the method handleRequest method. Can somone help me understand what is this method doing 'handlerequest' ? Any alternative to not use this method ? Because it is conflicting with someother thing which I'm trying to do.

```
 @Override
    public FutureResponse handleRequest(BackendRequestContext backendRequestContext, Request request, Metrics metrics) {
        return handleRequests(backendRequestContext, ImmutableList.of(request), metrics).get(0);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public List<FutureResponse> handleRequests(BackendRequestContext context, List<Request> requests, Metrics metrics) {
        StringRequest[] stringRequests = new StringRequest[requests.size()];

        final String language = context.locale().toLanguageTag().replace("-", "_");

        for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {
            final Request request = requests.get(i);

            final String id = request.requiredPathParam(STRING_ID_PATH_PARAM);
            final Optional<String> marketplaceDisplayName = request.queryParam(MARKETPLACE_NAME_QUERY_PARAM);
            final Optional<String> stage = request.queryParam(STAGE_QUERY_PARAM);

            final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(id);
            stringRequest.setLanguage(language);
            marketplaceDisplayName.ifPresent(stringRequest::setMarketplaceName);
            stage.map(Stage::getStage).ifPresent(stringRequest::setStage);
            stringRequests[i] = stringRequest;
        }

        ChainableFuture<StringResultBatch> batchFuture = ChainableFuture.immediate(invokeBatchSync(stringRequests));

        ImmutableList.Builder<FutureResponse> results = ImmutableList.builder();
        for (int i = 0; i < requests.size(); i++) {
            Request request = requests.get(i);
            int index = i;
            FutureResponse requestResponse = FutureResponse.of(request, batchFuture
                    .transform(batchResponse -> {
                        try {
                            if (batchResponse != null) {
                                return transform(request, batchResponse.get(index), language);
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
                            LOGGER.error("", e);
                        }
                        return Response.builder()
                                .withRequest(request)
                                .withEntityDescriptor(EntityDescriptors.ERROR_V1)
                                .withStatus(Http.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                                .withBody(ErrorResponses.ServerError.serviceUnavailable(ErrorResponse.InternalInfo.builder()
                                        .withMessage("Error retrieving ["
                                                + request.requiredPathParam(STRING_ID_PATH_PARAM)
                                                + "]")
                                        .build())
                                        .tokens())
                                .build();
                    }));

            results.add(requestResponse);
        }

        return results.build();
    }
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Your question is not clear, What have you tried? What were the results?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: How is Java supposed to know wich method to call.
Usually one would rename one methods but I see you are probably using conflicting interfaces. That way I'm afraid it's not possible to do so.
Did you write these interfaces yourself or are they beyond your controll?

However if reeaaaly want to do something like this you can only implement the interface for your second method and have a instance of the interface with the first mehtod ready like this:

```java
public class TestClass implements ConflictingInterface1{
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
    }
    public ConflictingInterface2 conflictingInterface2Instance=new ConflictingInterface2() {

        @Override
        public int method() {
            method();
            return 0;
        }};
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, the interfaces are beyond my control. I have to use either one of the interfaces. Can you help me understand the usage of method 1? Why are they simply returning method 2 please ? Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to return the second method right there instead of returning in the first method?